# Ordering colors into a multidimensional list

Tags: python, django

The code below works fine but seems really hard coded and I feel like I over-complicated the way it should be, I have a list containing hex and non-hex colors.

example : `['#333333', '#ff034a', 'red']`

Basically, hex colors are converted to RGB, the nouns are compared in the database and returns a list of hex if the noun matches a query.

Here's the Output I want to keep (could be a numpy output too) :

```
[[(38, 30, 38)], [(245, 245, 245)], [(255, 51, 51), (255, 153, 153), (217, 38, 38), (242, 13, 13), (255, 62, 62)]]
```

---

Here's the hard coded junk I want to keep short and make faster :

```
list_of_colors = ['#333333', '#ff034a', 'red'] #can contain from 1 to 3 values

def orderDimentionalRGB(list_of_colors):
    dominant = []
    secondary = []
    complementary = []

    for index, color in enumerate(list_of_colors): 
        if Color.objects.filter(color=color).exists(): #check for noun
            colors = Color.objects.filter(color=color)
            lst_colors = numpy.array(colors.first().color_list.replace(',', '').split())

            for lc in lst_colors:
                rgb = hex_to_rgb(lc) #returns from hex string -> to tuple rgb
                if index == 0:
                    dominant.append(rgb)
                elif index == 1:
                    secondary.append(rgb)
                else:
                    complementary.append(rgb)

        else: #check for rgb
            color = hex_to_rgb(color)

            if index == 0:
                dominant.append(color)
            elif index == 1:
                secondary.append(color)
            elif index == 2:
                complementary.append(color)

    colors = [dominant, secondary, complementary]
    set_colors = [x for x in colors if x]

    return set_colors
```

Maybe using that much `if, elif, else` and `array variables` becomes redundant and makes things slower, how can I improve this code ?

Comment: I think this code needs more context, where does `Color` come from? When and how is this code used?

Comment: @Ludisposed Color comes from a Django Model I don't think it's useful to understand django itself for this problem, just keep in mind that this will return a list of HEX. The final output will be used in a precis order like this [dominant, secondary, complementary]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as performance goes, you definitely need to understand your bottlenecks - profile the code properly and try to see what takes the most time - querying the database, converting hex to rgb or something else.

Here are few observations though:

- don't do `exists()` and then `filter()` - just do `filter()` right away - it will return an [empty queryset if no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304325/speeding-up-django-exists)
- I am not sure if there is much sense in making a `numpy.array` - see if removing it would make a positive impact on performance
- you don't need to keep track of indexes and then append to different lists based on an index - what if you would just collect the current results and then append to the resulting list at the end (see what I mean in the code below)
- if a color starts with `#` you probably don't need to query the database at all

At the end, you may get something along these lines:

```
def orderDimentionalRGB(list_of_colors):
    results = []

    for color in list_of_colors:
        current_result = []

        if color.startswith("#"):
            current_result.append(hex_to_rgb(color))
        else:
            db_result = Color.objects.filter(color=color)
            if db_result:
                db_colors = db_result.first().color_list.replace(',', '').split()
                current_result += [hex_to_rgb(db_color) for db_color in db_colors]

        if current_result:
            results.append(current_result)

    return results
```